# regex usage to find a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I have a task to do in my bash script. That I must read through a file and store all each word *Custom* in to array.
means my array will contain. `{"Custom_KEHJEO" "Custom_TTT_LEJEB_Adaptor" "ustom_SDE_Universal_Adaptor_EEEEEE"}`

I can read through the content of file starting from line 9 using sed command but unable to pick up 'Custom*' strings and store into array.

there is a file lets say ~ folders.txt with below content, starting from line 9 which is always the case, I have following text....
...and ending the last 3 lines also exactly same as below except date changes.

```
Custom_KEHJEO
Custom_TTT_LEJEB_Adaptor
Custom_SDE_Universal_Adaptor_EEEEEE
Custom_SIL_XXXXXXX
Custom_SIL_UUUUUUU
SDE_PSFT_89_Adaptor
SDE_SBL_78_Adaptor
UA_SDE
SILOS
SDE_SBL_Vert_811_Adaptor
SDE_JDEE1_90_Adaptor
SDE_Universal_Adaptor
Custom_SIL_XJGADWG
Custom_SIL_UUUUUUAAFE
SDE_ORAR12_Adaptor
SDE_JDEE1_811SP1_Adaptor
SDE_ORAR1212_Adaptor
SDE_ORA11510_Adaptor
SDE_SBL_80_Adaptor
Custom_SIL_MKEIHE
Custom_SDE_GAHWYWB
.listobjects completed successfully.

Completed at Thu Jan 22 12:46:39 2015
```

Comment: I think your goals require further clarification.  What's to become of those strings after they are captured in an array?  Will you write them to a file on a disk?  Provide them as parameters to another executable?

Comment: I will use them in another command because there is a command that expects each string as its input.....so that means I will use a -for loop- to supply each string from  the array as an input for that command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sanest way to do this is probably `grep`:

```
arr=($(grep ^Custom filename))

# arr is now a bash array containing all tokens that begin with Custom
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

You could also do it with sed:

```
arr=($(sed '/^Custom/!d' filename))
```

...but grep is really made for this. Note that this hinges on a file structure with one token per line.

Answer (score 0):

This will go ahead and pass each string as a parameter to your other executable.

```
INPUTFILE=folders.txt
for string in `tail -n+9 $INPUTFILE | grep ^Custom`; do
  othercommand $string
done
```

I just saw @Wintermute's answer, which is a good one.  If you actually need to capture these strings in an array for additional purposes other than just to pass to another command, @Wintermute's is more appropriate.